# Feed the Stanford Parser with a formatted text

Tags: parsing, stanford-nlp, pos-tagger, parse-tree

i have a phrase in the format  "Word_POS-TAG_Lemma Word_POS-TAG_Lemma Word_POS-TAG_Lemma Word_POS-TAG_Lemma....." is there a way to feed the stanford parser with this kind of formatted input? Moreover these is a way to obtain a tree in the standard dependencies way?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

See the FAQ: [*Can I give the parser part-of-speech (POS) tagged input and force the parser to use those tags?*](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#f)

It's definitely possible, though it would probably help to strip off / ignore the lemma forms to make things easier.